# AutoIt: Send left/right key with the returned value of inputBox

Tags: autoit

Is it possible for me to use a `Send("{LEFT}")` and `Send("{RIGHT}")` with the use of the value of my **inputBox?** My code is:

`$input = InputBox("Brightness", "Set Brightness to:", "", " M", -1, -1)
_UIA_action($oUIElement,"setfocus");`*focus on my control*

It's not working when I used

```
Send("{RIGHT" & $input &"}")
```

Or

```
Send("{LEFT" & $input &"}")
```

Is there other way to do it?

Comment: You have forgot the space between LEFT/RIGHT and the number (your input). *Send("{LEFT " & $input & "}")*

Comment: @McBarby still not working for me. I don't know what's the problem :(

Comment: Do you really know, what Send("{LEFT n}") does? It hits the "LEFT-ARROW-KEY" n-times. It moves the cursor in an input/edit control n-times to left. If a non-edit control has the focus, the movement is related to the application.

Comment: I do know what it does. But I don't think it will move the cursor to the left/right. It will just send left/right arrow keys.
I am trying to use the return value of my `$input` as a variable for the count of left/right keys which in my code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is quite confusing, but are you trying to repeat the `Send` key x times as defined in the input field? If so, this would be your code:

```
For $i = 1 To $input
    Send("{LEFT}")
Next
```